# Sailsjs request.param is null

Tags: sails.js

I created a new html form and submitted the form to a sails controller. Html input text box was bound with the property name for example  and then I had a submit button. Upon submitting the form I tried to retrieve the values from req.param["Mode"]. But this was always null. So quickly I changed the text field like this  and it started receiving the value from req.param["Model"]. I am surprised why this happens like this !

Answer (score 1):

`req.param` is not an array. It is a function you call it with the name of the value you want to retrieve, as a parameter, `req.param("<yourValue>")`.